# how do you make a reverse number pyramid in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a reverse pyramid that outputs

```
$ ./reverse_pyramid **3**

  1 2 3 2 1 
    1 2 1
      1
```

This is what I have but it outputs nothing and has no syntax errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

 # get input

read -p "Enter number:" num

 #outside of pyramid

for((i=1;i>=num;i--))
do

    #Loop to print numbers
    for((s=i;s>=num;s--))
    do
        echo -ne "@"
    done

    #left half
    for((j=1;j<=i;j++))
    do
        echo -ne "$j"
    done

    #right
    for((l=(i-1);l>=1;l--))
    do
        echo -ne "$l"
    done

    #add a line
    echo 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

It's due to this line:

```
for((i=1;i>=num;i--))
```

you're setting i to 1 which is smaller than your input num of 3 so your loop won't execute.

As a side note, I recommend you use -x option when debugging bash programs:

```
bash -x myprogram.sh
```

This will show you all the execution steps and pinpoints where it might be going wrong